# Integration of function when matrix is included in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector, matrix-multiplication, numerical-integration

I want to integrate a function which looks like

```
f <- function(x) 1.96 * sqrt(t(c(1,x)) %*% m %*% c(1,x))
```

where m is

```
m <- matrix(c(3.855, -0.206, -0.206, 0.01), nrow = 2, ncol = 2, byrow = T)
```

Since the matrix multiplication inside my function produces a scalar, for any value of `x`, this is just a one-dimensional integration for `f(x)`. How can I solve this smoothly?

Comment: What is your expected output given this sample data?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question? The sample data was something I put out there such that people understood that it was a 2x2 matrix and that in the end the matrix multiplication inside the function produced a scalar.

Comment: Not sure it's complicated. What are the actual values and the actual structure of the return value you are seeking. I think StéphaneLaurent's answer is the best, certainly, I was just asking for something along the lines of *"expecting 3.74"* or *"expecting a matrix of 7x14 with all 42s"* (obviously not that second one).

Comment: Actually I am trying to do a function within a function and this was the inner function. I am just expecting a scalar value as output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply with `integrate` and `Vectorize`:

```
integrate(Vectorize(f), lower = 0, upper = 1)
```

Comment: Efficient and elegant, upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option without `Vectorize` (but I believe the approach by [@Stéphane Laurent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69196065/12158757) is more space-efficient)

```
> ff <- function(x) 1.96 * sqrt(diag(t(rbind(1, x)) %*% m %*% rbind(1, x)))

> integrate(ff, lower = 0, upper = 1)
3.745299 with absolute error < 4.2e-14
```

where `ff` is already a vectorized function since it is constructed using `rbind` + `diag` to accept vector argument.

Comment: Actually this works better for my problem since I will doing a function within several functions, with this way I don't need to use Vectorize. Thank you for sharing!